# electron sqlite3 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I have built an electron app in Mac OS, when I try to export the package for windows and try to run it throws me following error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Fgd.png)

My app uses sqlite3, I installed sqlite using following command:

`npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source`

My `NODE_PATH` is also set to the node_modules folder, also tried following commands:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run "npm install", run this
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

But still I am not able to run sqlite3 on windows with electron

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3` relies on `node-pre-gyp`, so you need to use the [workaround](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild#node-pre-gyp-workaround) provided in `electron-rebuild` when building `sqlite3` for Electron.

Comment: When I use the electron-packager after I do `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`, I get the same error after executing the `exe` file (windows) same issue on OSX. Has anyone figured out what to do about it ?